# If we can derive that $\{x_{f(n)+1}\}$ converges to $a$ from that $\{x_{f(n)+1}\}$converges to $a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Just like in the title:
if a subsequence  $\{x_{f(n)}\}$ of $\{x_n\}$ converges to $a$,  and based on the fact that $\{x_{f(n)}\}$converges to $a$,  we can derive that $\{x_{f(n)+1}\}$, $\{x_{f(n)+2}\}$,$\{x_{f(n)+3}\}...$ also converge to $a$, is it true that $\{x_n\}$ converges to a? (It seems very true because it seems we can cover the whole sequence using (maybe infinite) converged subsequences)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please provide context to your question, if you want other members help you. Why is this question interesting for you? What did you tried in order to answer it?

Comment: A sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converges $\iff$ **all** of its subsequences $\{ x_{n_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge: in order to see if your proposition is true, you should choose carefully your subsequence  $\{ x_{n_k}\}_{k\in\mathbb{N}} =\{ x_{f(n)}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong.  A Counter example: $x_{n}=0$ for $n=t^2$, $x_n=1$ otherwise. And let $f(s)=s^2+1$.

Answer (score 7):

$x_{3n}=0, x_{3n+1}=0, x_{3n+2}=1$

Comment: So sorry I did not make myself clear. Please check the updated question.